# DHCP and static IP

Tags: dhcp

I have a server that dishes out IP addresses from 192.168.1.100 to .254.

I then have a linux client that must be assigned on 192.168.1.150 for a few days (this is done in the eth0 network script. If I do not put this IP in the DNS, i.e. only change the eth0 network script in the linux box, will this lead to conflict i.e. DHCP might dish out .150 address to another client, hence at least one of the client will not be able to be online.

Comment: Which DHCP server are you using?

Comment: And your question is...? (I'm guessing something like "what can I do to prevent such a conflict?" but it's better to be explicit; your question doesn't even include a `?` character.)

Comment: To avoid conflicts, if you're using the isc dhcp server, you can use the ping-check option. Windows dhcp server also has similar functionality to check before assigning. For more information, please let us know which dhcpd you're using.

Answer (score 3):

You have several clear choices:

1. Add an exclusion in your DHCP server so that it never distributes that address and continue assigning .150 manually
2. Add a reservation to your DHCP server so that .150 is always assigned to whatever MAC address eth0 is.